# ORDER BY slows down mysql query

Tags: mysql

We have one query which slows down our whole process.

This query takes about `10 seconds`

```
SELECT tbl_organisation.*,  
(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM tbl_user_organisation 
    WHERE tbl_user_organisation.organisation_id = tbl_organisation.id
) as members 
FROM tbl_organisation
WHERE tbl_organisation.archived = 0 
AND tbl_organisation.name LIKE "%name%"  
ORDER BY members
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Without the `ORDER BY` it takes only `76ms`

```
SELECT tbl_organisation.*,  
(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM tbl_user_organisation 
    WHERE tbl_user_organisation.organisation_id = tbl_organisation.id
) as members 
FROM tbl_organisation
WHERE tbl_organisation.archived = 0 
AND tbl_organisation.name LIKE "%name%"  
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

I know that the second just takes the first 10 rows and finishes and the first one has to sort the whole dataset first before selecting the 10 rows.

The question now is: Is it possible to make this query faster? And if yes how?

Since the `members` is dynamically counted we cannot add an `INDEX` to speed up queries like suggested in other solutions.

`EXPLAIN` of the slow query

[image]

Comment: sorry updated it

Comment: Hello @Mazz first thing first, please add `EXPLAIN ` prefix to the query and run it. MySQL will give you a report what is slow in the query. For each thing you can search and read how to fix it. Maybe indexes are missing or something. Cheers!

Comment: This query tells us the bottom 10 active organisations that match a name pattern (ranked by membership), right?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch i added the `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @Strawberry Right. The bottom 10 active organisations with the least members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer, but too long for a comment...

This query tells us the 10 least popular active organisations that match a name pattern, right?

In other words, it's functionally identical to:

```
SELECT o.*
     , COUNT(*) members
  FROM tbl_organisation o
  JOIN tbl_user_organisation uo
    ON uo.organisation_id = o.id
 WHERE o.archived = 0
   AND o.name LIKE "%name%" -- this is the slow bit in this query
 GROUP
    BY o.id 
 ORDER
    BY members ASC 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Executing this query shows the wrong amount of members in the organisation and only one result.

Comment: @Mazz Doh! Edited.

Comment: Well thanks this is exactly what i need and about 100 times faster. (Y)

Comment: It would be much faster still, if you could search for "name%" patterns (which can use an index) instead of "%name" patterns (which cannot).

Comment: @mazz  Please post results of EXPLAIN (your current query) so we can all see how the indexes are used rather than being full table scans as indicated by TYPE ALL.